# Minecraft losing lots of ticks on command functions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm losing a lot of server ticks to these command functions. Commandblocks are not enabled so it could not be anything like that. Anyone knows what is going on or how I can get rid of it?

Plugins:
Durability HUD datapack, Dynmap, Imageonmap, ChairStairs and SinglePlayerSleep

```
[01] |   commandFunctions(195/1) - 25.11%/25.11%
[02] |   |   minecraft:tick(195/1) - 99.90%/25.08%
[03] |   |   |   execute as @a store result score @s itm.info run data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage 1(195/1) - 3.34%/0.84%
[03] |   |   |   execute as @a if data entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage run title @s actionbar [{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"itm.output"}}](195/1) - 3.20%/0.80%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_boots"}}] itm.id 196(354/2) - 2.52%/0.63%
[03] |   |   |   execute as @a unless data entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage run title @s actionbar {"text":" "}(195/1) - 2.06%/0.52%
[03] |   |   |   execute as @a if data entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage run function durability:a(195/1) - 2.02%/0.51%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:bow"}}] itm.id 384(354/2) - 1.85%/0.46%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.78%/0.45%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_shovel"}}] itm.id 32(354/2) - 1.77%/0.44%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_boots"}}] itm.id 430(354/2) - 1.77%/0.44%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_sword"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.74%/0.44%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_helmet"}}] itm.id 78(354/2) - 1.74%/0.44%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_axe"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.68%/0.42%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate"}}] itm.id 241(354/2) - 1.62%/0.41%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:crossbow"}}] itm.id 326(354/2) - 1.62%/0.41%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:trident"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.59%/0.40%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.58%/0.40%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:flint_and_steel"}}] itm.id 64(354/2) - 1.58%/0.40%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:shears"}}] itm.id 238(354/2) - 1.58%/0.40%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:elytra"}}] itm.id 432(354/2) - 1.58%/0.40%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:shield"}}] itm.id 336(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"}}] itm.id 25(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_pickaxe"}}] itm.id 59(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_axe"}}] itm.id 59(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:fishing_rod"}}] itm.id 64(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_sword"}}] itm.id 59(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_shovel"}}] itm.id 59(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_sword"}}] itm.id 32(354/2) - 1.57%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_hoe"}}] itm.id 59(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:chainmail_helmet"}}] itm.id 165(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_axe"}}] itm.id 32(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_shovel"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_axe"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_shovel"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_sword"}}] itm.id 131(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_hoe"}}] itm.id 32(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_pickaxe"}}] itm.id 131(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_pickaxe"}}] itm.id 32(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_axe"}}] itm.id 131(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_hoe"}}] itm.id 250(354/2) - 1.56%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate"}}] itm.id 529(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_chestplate"}}] itm.id 113(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_leggings"}}] itm.id 226(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet"}}] itm.id 364(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_shovel"}}] itm.id 131(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:chainmail_chestplate"}}] itm.id 240(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_hoe"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe"}}] itm.id 131(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings"}}] itm.id 496(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:iron_helmet"}}] itm.id 166(354/2) - 1.55%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:turtle_helmet"}}] itm.id 276(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:chainmail_leggings"}}] itm.id 225(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:chainmail_boots"}}] itm.id 195(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_boots"}}] itm.id 1561(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:gold_leggings"}}] itm.id 92(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings"}}] itm.id 76(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"}}] itm.id 56(354/2) - 1.54%/0.39%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate"}}] itm.id 81(354/2) - 1.53%/0.38%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players set @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:leather_boots"}}] itm.id 66(354/2) - 1.53%/0.38%
[03] |   |   |   unspecified(195/1) - 1.06%/0.27%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players operation @s itm.output = @s itm.id(354/2) - 0.10%/0.03%
[03] |   |   |   function durability:a(354/2) - 0.03%/0.01%
[03] |   |   |   scoreboard players operation @s itm.output -= @s itm.info(354/2) - 0.02%/0.00%
```

Answer (score 3):

I am Leon Nikolai Engelsvold, the creator of the [Durability Hud Datapack](https://www.planetminecraft.com/data-pack/durability-hud/). If you have installed the datapack from any site other than [Planetminecraft](https://www.planetminecraft.com/data-pack/durability-hud/), curseforge or [Github](https://github.com/LeonNikolai/Durability-Hud-Datapack) it's likely you have an outdated version, as I do not administer listings on other sites.

### I did at the time not consider servers using the datapack.

Earlier versions of the Datapack performed badly because it checked all players `SelectedItem` every `minecraft:tick`. When used on servers containing larger amounts of people, the datapack would yield bad server performance results. I did at the time not consider servers using the datapack.

### Fixed / Improved performance in newer versions.

New versions perform much better because of optimizations only checking on inventory or hotbar changes rather than every tick, done by utilizing advancements rather than `minecraft:tick` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a bad datapack installed which created the problem. I was using the durability hud datapack and it was creating problems.